# Text appearing outside Bootstrap 3 well

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am dynamically creating a Bootstrap well in which some entered text should be displayed using JavaScript and CSS/HTML. My code is given below:

```
$("#addqueuebutton").click(function(){

    var queue = '<div class="well queue-well">';
    queue += '<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a></span>';
    queue += '<div class="inline"><h3>&nbsp ' + $('#queuename').val() + '</h3></div>';
    queue += '</div>';
    $('#queues').append(queue);
});
```

My CSS:

```
.queue-well{
    height: 30px;
}
```

My problem is, the text I am entering (`$('#queuename').val()`) is appearing outside the well. I want it be present inside the well. I tried using `clearfix` in the `div class='well'` line, but it didn't work. Does anyone know how I could fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'<a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></a></span>'` this line has mismatched closing tags.

Comment: @alan0xd7 oh, right, thank you, I corrected that. The earlier problem remains, though.

Comment: create a fiddle so that I can help you out

Comment: @Ajey Here it is: https://jsfiddle.net/cgzpe9yw/

Comment: you can just copy the given JS and CSS and replace $('#queuename').val() with some random text if the full result is not showing in the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by your css `height: 30px;` as it restricts the well size, so it cannot expand to the size of its contents.

If you simply remove this style then it will work correctly.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/alan0xd7/cgzpe9yw/6/

Answer (score 0):

Demo [Here](http://jsbin.com/qapeju/edit?css,js,output)

Steps -

Remove `height: 30px;` and add

```
.queue-well .inline {
  display: inline-block;
}
```